# Batch code to move certain file types to new folder

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I want to move file names from one folder to another folder when they are populated in the original folder. What is throwing me off is it has to only be a part of the file name. For example

File name to be moved: `This_file_Move_it29141.txt`
How do I set requirements for just "this_file_move" starting and ending with a .txt

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off


Set Filespath=d:\From\Here
set DestPath=d:\To\to here


for /f %%X in (%%) do call :Move_Files "%%X"
goto :eof

:MOVE_FILES
for /r %d:\crmintegration\ConsoleApplications %%I in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `dir /b` to get a matching filename listing.

```
@echo off

set sourcepath=D:\source
set destpath=D:\dest

set searchstring=This_file_Move

set files='dir /b "%sourcepath%\%searchstring%*.txt"' 2> NUL
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (    
    for /f %%a in (%files%) do (
        echo Moving %%a...
        move /y "%sourcepath%\%%a" "%destpath%\"
    )
)
```

The `%files%` variable is optional, but allows you to skip a `File not found` error if no matching files are found in the source directory. If you don't care about that, you can put the `dir` command directly into the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "Filespath=d:\From\Here"
    set "DestPath=d:\To\to here"

    if exist "%Filespath%\This_file_move_*.txt" (
        move "%Filespath%\This_file_move_*.txt" "%DestPath%"
    )

    endlocal
```

To prevent errors, first check if files exist and then move them to the target folder.